# rails - Parsing an Email Message for just the reply, not the old thread?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I set my app to receive incoming emails via a post from a service. The controller that receives the posts looks a little like this:

```
    class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController    
      require 'mail'
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

      def create
        message = Mail.new(params[:message])
        message_plain = (params[:plain])
        Rails.logger.info   'message2.plain:'
        Rails.logger.info   message2

        render :text => 'success', :status => 200 # a status of 404 would reject the mail
      end
    end
```

That successfully is delivering the entire email message, replies,forward history etc. The issue is I'd like to be able to extract just the actual reply text.

Currently I get:

```
That's not a bad idea. Lets try that out.

On Nov 17, 2010, at 4:18 PM, XXXXX @ XXXXXXXX wrote:
> There's a new reply:
```

And I'd like to know how rails devs get just the reply:

```
That's not a bad idea. Lets try that out.
```

Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Normally you'd insert a separator in your original message for the user to put his reply above or below. In this case you'd need to drop all lines starting with a `>` + the last remaining line the message.

Comment: Thanks but that wouldn't get everything

Answer (score 3):

There's no guaranteed way to get the entire message however it's common practice to make use of a separator and then use some code to parse out the response line.

If you take a look at the code in the open source project teambox for example you see the something really similar to the following:

```
def strip_responses(body)
# For GMail. Matches "On 19 August 2010 13:48, User <proj+conversation+22245@app.teambox.com<proj%2Bconversation%2B22245@app.teambox.com>> wrote:"
body.strip.
  gsub(/\n[^\r\n]*\d{2,4}.*\+.*\d@app.teambox.com.*:.*\z/m, '').
  split("---------separator---------").first.
  split("<div class='email'").first.
  strip
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect gem, but you could try this gem from Github: [Email Reply Parser](https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [extended_email_reply_parser](https://github.com/fiedl/extended_email_reply_parser), which also includes [github's email_reply_parser](https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser).

#### Install

Add it to the `Gemfile`:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'extended_email_reply_parser'
```

#### Usage

Then, you can parse the email reply like this:

```
message_plain = ExtendedEmailReplyParser.parse message
```

#### Example

Applied to your code:

```
class IncomingMailsController < ApplicationController    
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    message = Mail.new(params[:message])
    message_plain = ExtendedEmailReplyParser.parse(message)

    render :text => 'success', :status => 200 # a status of 404 would reject the mail
  end
end
```

#### email_reply_parser vs. extended_email_reply_parser

The **email_reply_parser** is used and developed by github. It's small and efficient, but can't handle some edge cases, where the sender's email client doesn't properly format the previous conversation as quote.

The **extended_email_reply_parser** is an extendible wrapper around github's parser. It's not as efficient as the original one. But, it's easier to extend if the typical emails you're parsing are not handled quite right out of the box.

#### Resources

- [email_reply_parser](https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser)
- [extended_email_reply_parser](https://github.com/fiedl/extended_email_reply_parser)
- [Examples for extending the parser](https://github.com/fiedl/extended_email_reply_parser#helper-methods-for-writing-parsers)